# Failed to run simple file Miktex with Window10

Tags: xetex, miktex, windows

i had installed Miktex and updated it, tried this example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
hallow
\end{document}
```

i have this error:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (MiKTeX 22.10) (preloaded format=xelatex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

Sorry, but C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-xetex.exe did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\...\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-xetex.log
```

The miktex.log is:
'''

```
2022-11-07 21:31:45,226+0100 INFO  miktex - this is One MiKTeX Utility 1.4 (MiKTeX 22.10)
2022-11-07 21:31:45,226+0100 INFO  miktex - this process (14156) started by miktex-xetex in directory C:\...\Documents\AtefLatex with command line: miktex formats build xelatex --engine xetex
2022-11-07 21:31:45,226+0100 INFO  miktex - Building format 'xelatex' with engine 'xetex'...
2022-11-07 21:31:45,242+0100 INFO  miktex.core - start process: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=xetex --dest-name=xelatex --no-dump xelatex.ini --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose
2022-11-07 21:31:47,513+0100 ERROR miktex - sub-process error output has been saved to 'C:\...\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makefmt_2022-11-07-213147.out'
2022-11-07 21:31:47,513+0100 FATAL miktex - The executed process did not succeed.
2022-11-07 21:31:47,513+0100 FATAL miktex - Info: fileName="C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makefmt.exe", exitCode="1"
2022-11-07 21:31:47,513+0100 FATAL miktex - Source: 
2022-11-07 21:31:47,513+0100 FATAL miktex - Line: 0
2022-11-07 21:31:47,513+0100 INFO  miktex - this process (14156) finishes with exit code 1
```

'''
The miktex.makefmt.log is:
'''

```
2022-11-07 21:31:47,467+0100 FATAL miktex-makefmt - miktex-xetex.exe failed on xelatex.ini.
2022-11-07 21:31:47,467+0100 FATAL miktex-makefmt - miktex-xetex.exe failed on xelatex.ini.
2022-11-07 21:31:47,467+0100 FATAL miktex-makefmt - Info: 
2022-11-07 21:31:47,467+0100 FATAL miktex-makefmt - Source: 
2022-11-07 21:31:47,467+0100 FATAL miktex-makefmt - Line: 0
2022-11-07 21:31:47,498+0100 INFO  miktex-makefmt - this process (13060) finishes with exit code 1
```

'''
The miktex-makefmt_2022-11-07-213147.out is:
'''

```
! LaTeX Error: File 'UnicodeData.txt' not found.
```

'''
Can anyone help me please??

Comment: well difficult. This unicode-data error is quite mysterious. See e.g. https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1121. If an update doesn't help you are probably out of luck. Try lualatex instead of xelatex.

Comment: Lualatex is the same like xelatex, pdflatex doesn*t work